# SQL Server stored procedure for ASP classic

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, asp-classic

I am iterating over an html table.

Each row has an id, and the table has 2 columns/2 properties.

Here is my loop:

```
Dim id
    Dim prop1
    Dim prop2

For Each id In Request.Form("id")
    prop1 = Request.Form(id & "_prop1")
    prop1 = Request.Form(id & "_prop2")
Next
```

Imagine I want to update the data in my database... I might put in that loop

```
"UPDATE table SET prop1 = '" & prop1 & "', prop2 = '" & prop2 & "'" WHERE id = '" & id & 
"'"
```

What is a SQL stored procedure and how would I go about implementing one for this operation?

For example in this link: http://www.albofish.co.uk/ms-sql-stored-procedures-and-classic-asp/

I see no reference to the table you are to be updating... I just don't understand it. d'oh

With this example: http://www.ehow.com/way_5901555_tutorial-sql-stored-procedures.html

I cannot see how I am to put my form values into the procedure?

Comment: Look online about stored procedures -- do a little research and then post what you don't understand.  In regards to your SQL above, your UPDATE statement should be UPDATE Table SET Field ... WHERE ID ...  -- SET comes before WHERE.

Comment: Okay, the question might be, is the procedure a function inside my database... Or is it a function I declare in my asp code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A stored procedure lives in your backend database, not your ASP code. What's probably confusing you in the link you posted is that it contains the *client-side* code that's used to execute the *server-side* procedure, which isn't shown.

In your case, the actual stored procedure itself would look something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyProcedure
(
   @prop1 varchar(255), --Fill in appropriate data types if necessary
   @prop2 varchar(255),
   @id int
)
AS
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE table
  SET prop1 = @prop1,
      prop2 = @prop2
  WHERE id = @id;
```

(@sgeddes is right that the procedure should include `SET NOCOUNT ON`. I've added that to my example.)

Then you would use the following client-side code to call that procedure (I've edited the code from your link to make it easier to follow).

```
'Create ADO command
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With cmd
   'Set up DB connection to use, set the type of SQL command
   .ActiveConnection = db
   .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
   .CommandText = "dbo.MyProcedure" ' Set the name of the Stored Procedure to use

   'Add a 255 character varchar parameter
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@prop1",adVarChar, adParamInput, 255)
   .Parameters("@prop1") = "Prop 1 Value"

   'Add a 255 character varchar parameter
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@prop2",adVarChar, adParamInput, 255)
   .Parameters("@prop2") = "Prop 2 Value"

   'Add a integer parameter, then pass the value of the variable userID to it
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@id",adInteger, adParamInput)
   .Parameters("@id") = userID

   'Execute the command
   .Execute
End With

'Clean up
set cmd = nothing
```

That's obviously a lot more code than what you have right now. So why would you do it? The most important reason is security. By creating a parameterized procedure and passing the values in parameters, you drastically reduce the likelihood of any sort of SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 0):

A SQL Stored Procedure is different than an ASP Function -- a Stored Procedure is something you create in your database.  The syntax is different depending on your RDBMS.  But something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateYourTable
    @id int, 
    @prop1 nvarchar(50).
    @prop2 nvarchar(50)
AS 

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE table 
    SET prop1 = @prop1, prop2 = @prop2 
    WHERE id = @id

GO
```

You would then call this stored procedure through your code very much like the article you posted.